# What's the difference between these two implementation in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'd like to know if there is a difference, **performance wise** between:

1) in the same port:

```
var http = require('http');

http.Server(function (req, res) {
  if (req.url == 'foo') { foo(); return;}
  if (req.url == 'bar') { bar(); }
}).listen(123);
```

2) splitted on 2 ports

```
var http = require('http');

http.Server(function (req, res) {
  foo();
}).listen(123);

http.Server(function (req, res) {
  bar();
}).listen(456);
```

3) in 2 separate js file that I would launch on 2 different node cmd.

`foo()` and `bar()` being functions that can take time to resolve like uploading files for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#1 and #2 will be basically identical in terms of performance. If you run two servers like in #3 and you have a multi-core machine you will be able to perform up to twice as many simultaneous requests, depending on the IO required and available.

Comment: Well, if the workload is I/O-bound, having two CPU will not speed it up (otherwise node.js would not make any sense at all). Of course, if the workload is CPU-heavy, it would help a lot.

Comment: Yup, that's why I said "depending on the IO required and available" :)

Answer (score 1):

Two different node instances give you two CPU threads (but use up more memory and cannot easily share state). That is the only real difference I can see.